# Chicken or the egg with pytest fixtures

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I want to use the `record_xml_property` fixture.
No problem.  It works perfectly when it is presently available.
However, I want my tests to run smoothly whether this fixture is installed or not.  When I create a 'wrapper' fixture, 
(something like this)

```
//this one works nicely when record_xml_property is there
@pytest.fixture()   
def real_property_handler( record_xml_property, mykey, myval):
    record_xml_property( mykey, myval)

//this does a harmless print instead
@pytest.fixture()  
def fallback_property_handler( mykey, myval):
    print('{0}={1}].format( mykey, myval))

def MyXMLWrapper( mykey, myval):  
    try:      # I want to use the REAL one if I can
        real_property_handler( record_xml_property, mykey, myval)
    except:   # but still do something nice if it's not
        fallback_property_handler( mykey, myval)
```

**My test should not have to be cognizant**
**of any fixture(s) that may or may not underlie my wrapper function**

```
def test_simple():  
    MyXMLWrapper( 'mykeyname', 'mykeyvalue')
    assert True
```

I'm stuck because in order for my tests to ever work properly it appears that I have to pass the `record_xml_property` fixture as a parameter which I can never do in environments that don't have this fixture installed.
I've tried several things.
If I make `MyXMLWrapper` a fixture itself then I have to pass it the `record_xml_fixture`, but if I define `MyXMLWrapper` as a function (above) then I have no way to reference the `record_xml_property` in case it DOES exist.

What am I not understanding here about how fixtures work?
Thanks.

Comment: By "whether this fixture is installed," do you mean "whether the version of pytest in use provides the fixture" (i.e., whether pytest is 2.8 or higher) or something else?  If this is just a dependency versioning issue, why can't you just specify `pytest>=2.8` in your `test-requirements.txt` or equivalent?

Comment: yes.  I want it to be version independent.
(reason being is that some test case environs are fixed to a particular Os release and python version)

Comment: any test function (**def test_whatever(...**  ) is capable of referencing any pytest fixtures that it wants, e.g.

{
def test_mytest( record_xml_property, parm1, parm2):
    record_xml_property( parm1, parm2)
}

so I guess all I really need to know is how can I reference a pytest fixture from within my own function which is not itself a standalone test function?  (ie. no **test_** in it's name)